# sql ошибка номер 1064

Tags: mariadb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]        BACKUP DATABASE mydata
        TO DISK = 'D:\backups\testDB.bak';

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near  'BACKUP DATABASE mydata TO DISK = 'D:\backups\testDB.bak'' at line 1

что не правильно? только начал изучать таблицы, пока ничего не пониаю

Comment: Нет такого типа запроса, как `BACKUP DATABASE`. Более того, бэкап для сервера обычно внешний процесс. Читай внимательно [Backing Up and Restoring Databases](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/backing-up-and-restoring-databases/).

Comment: добавил картинку откуда узнал про  этот запрос, это же вроде не самый  последний сайт

Comment: Замените картинку (ну не лечим мы по фотографиям!) на работающую ссылку. И - посмотрите попристальнее, о каком именно SQL-сервере идёт речь по ссылке... вот ни разу это не MySQL/MariaDB...